# Invoke .NET C# web service from Android, using complex data type

Tags: c#, .net, android

I need to call a web service using ksoap2, from Android! The real problem I am facing is that, I have to use a complex data type. ( a class containing two strings ). Does anybody have an example of passing a complex type to a webservice, preferably, only using SoapObject?